# 403 Forbidden BeautifulSoup Web Scraper

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I was building a web scraper to pull hrefs off of https://www.startengine.com/explore, but I was struggling to get any hrefs. I decided to print the webpage and figured out why.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL = "https://www.startengine.com/explore"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

links = []
print(soup)
```

This is the output:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me work around the "403 Forbidden"?

Comment: Yes, it's probably a bot prevention. You're writing a bot, they don't want you doing this. You should respect that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073209/403-forbidden-output-while-using-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject  your user-agent as header as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL = "https://www.startengine.com/explore"
headers={'User-Agent':'mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
print(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

links = []
print(soup)
```