# 403 Forbidden or access denied for some website why?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

when scraping from website using bs4 it showing response object as access denied and Forbidden how  to solve this?

Comment: The question is similar [HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055208/httperror-http-error-403-forbidden/13055444#13055444)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055208/httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the required headers such as 'User-Agent' before firing the get Request. In most cases, if 'User-Agent' is not provided, you'll end up with 403 response.

Comment: Good answer, to make it more clear: you should use a browser's User-Agent, which you can view by browsing to `whichbrowser.net` in your favorite browser

Comment: correct, for instance mozillas UA would be, 
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

Comment: I am using google chrome to scrape data from website using beautifulsoup