# BeautifulSoup not returning full html - 403 Forbidden?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am having issues with parsing a website. There seems to be a "403 Forbidden" error. Does that mean I cannot scrape through the website? If so, is there some sort of work around?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

URL = 'https://frequentmiler.com/best-credit-card-sign-up-offers/'
webpage = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

This returns:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   403 Forbidden
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
   <h1>
    403 Forbidden
   </h1>
  </center>
  <hr/>
  <center>
   nginx
  </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python requests. 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden)

Comment: check out the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71018471/10729303) thread.

Answer (score 3):

The website is knowing that you're trying to get a source page from a python code, you must escape this by adding a **user-agent** in request headers.

```
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"}
webpage = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
```

And now, you are like a human surfer using a simple web browser =).

Comment: Amazing.. that worked! How did you determine the user-agent value? Thank you!

Comment: I just tried, but on the first try, I've got it.
A little bit of experience and you will able to determine those tricks, keep working! :D

Answer (score 0):

That means that you're not authorized to view that url.